# Rviz 'base map' at a different initial position compared to Gazebo world

Tags: ros, gazebo, rviz, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I launched the turtlebot3 using

```
roslaunch turtlebot3_gazebo
turtlebot3_world.launch
```

and then launched the ROS navigation stack and some other nodes using

```
roslaunch turtlebot3_navigation
turtlebot3_navigation.launch
```

I see that the default map in the Rviz is centered differently than the Gazebo. Why is that and how can I sync them?

Here's an image showing that -
[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/348045/rviz-%27base-map%27-at-a-different-initial-position-compared-to-gazebo-world/) by [Shivendra](https://answers.ros.org/users/35418/shivendra/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2020-03-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi @Shivendra,

The difference you see between Gazebo and the map is actually the normal behaviour when you launch the navigation for the first time. Since you are using [AMCL](http://wiki.ros.org/amcl) to localize the robot in the map, you need to provide AMCL with a first pose estimate in order to begin the localization process.

This can be done by clicking in the top Panel of Rviz named `2D Pose Estimate` and clicking again in the map in the "real" pose the robot is placed in the Gazebo world. You will see how AMCL corrects its estimations and the Pose array provided significantly decreases the uncertainty.

---

Originally posted by [Weasfas](https://answers.ros.org/users/34184/weasfas/) with karma: 1695 on 2020-04-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Shivendra](https://answers.ros.org/users/35418/shivendra/) on 2020-04-05**:
Thanks for the response and the explanation. I could manage to sync that but I did it slightly differently. I changed the initial pose arguments in the `amcl.launch` file to match the initial pose in `turtlebot3_world.launch`. I thought the GUI based way via RViz would make the pose almost the same but not pinpoint same.